# Flash duplicateMovieclip and place in other movieclip (AS2)

Tags: flash, duplicates, actionscript-2, movieclip

for some reason then i duplicate movie clip and try to put it in other movie clip, it doesn't work. In scene i got 2 movie clips mc and mc2. Then i use AS to create new movie clip, and  place in existing movie clip, it creates it in _root directory...

Here's the code:

```
   duplicateMovieClip(_root.mc, "_root.mc2.name", 1);
```

Any help?:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't duplicate a movieclip in different levels in AS2.
If you want to use a loaded image many times, you can duplicate the movieclip in the same level or load the image as many times as you need directly in the final clip.

You can also use the attachMovie function in any moveclip if you can put the image in your library.